# Path space vs loop space

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

If we consider the path fibration over a topological space $X$ we have
$$ \Omega(X;p,p) \hookrightarrow P(X) \to X .$$
Where I denote with $\Omega(X;p,p)$ the set of paths $\omega:[0,1] \to X$ such that $\omega(0)=\omega(1)=p$. Why if we suppose that $X=M$ a Riemannian manifold, the space $\Omega(M,p,p)$ is homotopically equivalent to path space $\Omega(M;p,q)$ where $q \in M$ is not necessary equal to p?

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume $M$ is connected so that there is a path from $p$ to $q$; if this assumption isn't satisfied then the assertion to be proved is false.  So fix a path $\alpha$ from $p$ to $q$.  Map $\Omega(p,p)$ to $\Omega(p,q)$ by sending each path $\gamma\in\Omega(p,p)$ to the concatenation $\gamma\alpha$; in the opposite direction, map $\Omega(p,q)$ to $\Omega(p,p)$ by sending each $\beta\in\Omega(p,q)$ to $\beta\alpha^{-1}$ (where $\alpha^{-1}$ is $\alpha$ traversed backward).  The composition of these two transformations, in either order, is homotopic to the identity, because both $\alpha\alpha^{-1}$ and $\alpha^{-1}\alpha$ are homotopic to constant paths.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with being a manifold.

Comment: @BabyDragon  If $M$ weren't a manifold, then "connected" should be "pathwise connected" in the first sentence of my answer.  But apart from this use of the local pathwise connectedness of manifolds, the proof is quite general.

Comment: I try not think about such spaces.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I'm sorry, but I think my assertion is wrong. Infact the fibre of application $P(M) \to M$ is $\Omega(M;p,q)$ and not $\Omega(M;p,p)$.